# How do I set up AU Lab with Soundflower to record and monitor all audio that is playing on my Mac Pro?

Tags: recording

How do I set up AU Lab with Soundflower to record and monitor all audio that is playing on my Mac Pro?
                        K.W.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to set Soundflower as the default output for audio (System Preferences->Sound), otherwise it will only accept input from whichever program has been specifically set to send output to Soundflower. Then in AU Lab, select Soundflower as the default input. This should capture everything.